# Wordpress & woocommerce get products by product_category and partial SKU match

Tags: php, wordpress

I am wanting to return a list of products that belong to a certain set of product_categories and also have a SKU that start with a certain pattern of string, so far I have the following, but it seems to be ignoring the `meta_query`

```
$args = [
        'status' => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'meta_query' => [
            'key' => '_sku',
            'value' => '^RE-',
            'compare' => 'REGEXP'
        ],
        'tax_query' => [
            'relation' => 'AND',
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $cat_id,
            ],
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => 789,
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $query = new WC_Product_Query($args);
    $products = $query->get_products();
    die(print_r($products));
```

I get the products from the `tax_query` but it seems to be ignoring the `meta_query` as any SKU is being returned?

Comment: Even if you have only one set of meta conditions, you still need to make `meta_query` an array inside an array, and not just an array. Same format as you used with `tax_query`, only with just one set of conditions, and without any need for a `relation` either.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters: _"(Note that meta_query expects nested arrays, even if you only have one query.)"_